# Displaying data in percentage in the attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, calculate-values

I'm trying to figure out how to display one attribute column in percentages. I've created a new field inside the attribute table and proceeded with:

```
concat("column with numbers to be changed in percentage", '%')
```

But the output displays `NULL`. Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you just looking to put a % at the end of a number, or are you trying to convert a decimal to a whole number as a percent?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I'm trying to convert a decimal to a whole number as a percent!

Comment: Gotcha!! Let me add an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given decimal values in a double precision column (or other), you can use an expression to:

- multiply the value by 100
- round the value to 0 decimal places
- concatenate the % sign at the end of the value

In a label expression, this is what I would do:

*(my percent column is called "rating")*

```
round(("rating"*100), 0) || '%'
```

I use the label expression rather than creating a new column of otherwise redundant data.

[image]

Here I've added both the original column and the percent-formatted column on two lines of the label:

```
"rating" ||  '\n' ||
round(("rating"*100), 0) || '%'
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, great input cheers!

Comment: @Guillaume good stuff! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

you need to use to_string expression, when use numbers in concat, like this:

```
concat(to_string("column with numbers to be changed in percentage"), ' %')
```

I hope, this will be helpful for you.

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your input, however, the result of the formula is still giving me "NULL"...

Comment: @Guillaume, I prove the code, and words in my Qgis, It is possible that you are using a field that can support string, or is not possible to edit this field, try to create a new column that supports string, I think this will works.

I edit the answer to you can reply the code.

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate two strings, you can use the `||` operator.

So the expression would look like this:

```
 to_string("column with numbers to be changed in percentage" ) || '%'
```