# QGIS Field calculator Problem: Display percentage

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

[image]So basically  I have this formula which puts out decimal numbers, but I want it to output percentages.
How can I achieve this?

This is my formula:

```
(("crimes_2020" - ("crimes_2017_2019" / 3)) / ("crimes_2017_2019" / 3)) * 100
```

Comment: Can you please show the attribute table ?

Comment: Otherwise use `round(...,2)`. If the output field is text, than `round(...,2) || %`

Comment: i added picture . also thanks for answering

Comment: Use `round()`, I think this is what you need. Can values be also negative ? If not don’t forget about `abs()`.

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348527/display-data-in-percentage-in-attribute-table-qgis